# Sample mean converging to normal much faster than expected.

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, means, confidence-interval

I am taking a non-normal distribution (Poisson, Exponential or Uniform etc.) and I simulate thousands of experiments for small sample sizes ($n=1,...,10$). I calculate the 95%-confidence interval each time, using:
$$I_{0.95}=\bigg(\hat{\mu}+z_{0.025}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}, \ \ \hat{\mu}-z_{0.025}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\bigg)$$
where $\hat{\mu}$ is my estimate for the mean (sample mean). I am also always assuming $\sigma$ is known (I am just taking it from the distribution I chose at the beginning).

Now, I have noticed a strange behaviour, namely, the estimates for confidece intervals are correct approximately 95% of them for whatever size of a sample. I thought that we should get a value around 95% only after, say, $n>30$.

Is this because the variance is known?

Below is a graph for $n=2,3,...,100$, each time 10,000 simulations. Uniform distribution.
[image]

The below picture is a reference to @grand_chat 's comment.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try computing confidence intervals for samples from distributions that deviate more from normality. For example, try generating observations from a Poisson distribution with $\lambda=.001$. You'll find that your $z$-theory intervals will not have the advertised coverage.

In general, you'll find that the normal theory works pretty well if the distribution you're sampling from is reasonably symmetric, so aim for samples from non-symmetric distributions, or distributions that are almost a point mass, such as Poisson with tiny $\lambda$. Keep away from the uniform distribution; the normal approximation kicks in pretty quickly no matter how you scale it.

Knowing the variance takes some of the 'noise' out of the confidence interval. So yes, this will improve coverage over using an estimator for the standard deviation.

Comment: I have simulated a Poisson distribution with $\lambda=0.001$. You can see what I got in the question, I have added a graph. This confuses me even more, I have checked my code and I believe I didn't make any mistakes.

Comment: It's a discontinuity issue, I believe. For $\lambda=0.01$ I got the downward-sloping lines, each next with decreasing slope. Could you give an example of a continuous distribution, which wouldn't be covered properly by z-test?

Comment: This is expected behavior: there's nothing wrong with your code. You are right, the discreteness of the sample mean for tiny $\lambda$ causes the sloping lines.  Try with $\lambda=.1$ and the behavior will right itself more quickly.

Comment: For a continuous distribution that doesn't work well with the $z$-test, your best bet is a highly skewed distribution with a long tail.

Comment: I have tried with exponential, chi-square and all of them work extremely fine with z-test. Would you be able to give me a particular example? I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Try a lognormal distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution. To simulate a lognormal, sample from a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ and exponentiate the value you get. The result will have lognormal distribution with location parameter $\mu$ and scale parameter $\sigma$. For example $\mu=1$ and $\sigma=3$ should have enough of a long tail to throw off the $z$-test CI.

Comment: True, it completely destroyed z-test and t-test, even for big values of $n$. Thank you very much for that!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with non-normal distributions, shouldn't you be using tests for non-normally distributed data? Also, when the sample size is less than 30, you would usually conduct a t-test. In this case, the t-test equivalents for non-normally distributed data are the following:Mann-Whitney test, Mood’s median test, and Kruskal-Wallis test.

Comment: I assume that I don't know what the distribution is, however, I know the actual variance. In my simulations, t-test works pretty poorly for small $n$. It gives about 97-98% of correct intervals, while z-test is very accurate.

Comment: I've added a picture to show that.